# How do I change which application is controlled by the audio controll keys?

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, audio-player

I'm sorry if this is an obvious question. When I have a video open in my browser and an mp3 file playing in VLC, how do I change which application is controlled by the play/pause and forward/backward keys?

Intuitively I would expect the last application to be used to be controlled by these keys, but that doesn't seem to be the case. For me, the browser video is tied to the shortcuts, even if I've been using VLC last.

Thanks you all!

Comment: The one that is set as default for that specific type of file?

Comment: Well, Firefox p.ex. seems to grab focus away from VLC playing mp3 files if a video is open somewhere in the browser, and there does not seem to be away to focus on VLC again.